How to use custom POJOs for table and column classes with jOOQ's CLI tool for translating SQLite queries to Java?
I'm using jOOQ's CLI tool to translate my SQLite queries into Java code. The tool works well, but I noticed it uses table and column names as strings in the generated queries. I found that there's an option to provide a database schema, which allows the tool to generate POJOs for the tables and columns, and then uses those classes in the generated Java code.
However, instead of using the generated POJOs, I want to use my own custom POJOs that I've already created for the tables and columns. Is there a way to instruct jOOQ's CLI tool to use my custom POJOs instead of generating new ones?
Example scenario:
Assume I have an SQLite query like this:
FROM users u 
JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id 
WHERE u.active = 1;

When I use jOOQ's CLI tool without a schema, it generates something like:
DSL.select(field("u.name"), field("o.order_date"))
   .from(table("users").as("u"))
   .join(table("orders").as("o")).on(field("u.id").eq(field("o.user_id")))
   .where(field("u.active").eq(1))
   .fetch();

By providing the schema, jOOQ generates POJOs like Users and Orders and the code becomes:
DSL.select(USERS.NAME, ORDERS.ORDER_DATE)
   .from(USERS.as("u"))
   .join(ORDERS.as("o")).on(USERS.ID.eq(ORDERS.USER_ID))
   .where(USERS.ACTIVE.eq(1))
   .fetch();

But I want to use my custom POJOs, such as MyUsers and MyOrders, which are defined as follows:
public class MyUsers {
    public static final Table<MyUsers> TABLE = ...
    public static final Field<String> NAME = ...
    public static final Field<Integer> ID = ...
    public static final Field<Boolean> ACTIVE = ...
}

public class MyOrders {
    public static final Table<MyOrders> TABLE = ...
    public static final Field<Integer> USER_ID = ...
    public static final Field<Date> ORDER_DATE = ...
}

I would like the generated code to look like this:
DSL.select(MyUsers.NAME, MyOrders.ORDER_DATE)
   .from(MyUsers.TABLE.as("u"))
   .join(MyOrders.TABLE.as("o")).on(MyUsers.ID.eq(MyOrders.USER_ID))
   .where(MyUsers.ACTIVE.eq(true))
   .fetch();

My questions:

CLI tool configuration: Is there a way to configure jOOQ's CLI tool
to use my custom POJOs instead of generating new ones?
jOOQ API: If the CLI tool doesn't support this, is it possible to
achieve this using jOOQ's API programmatically? If so, could you
provide an example or point me in the right direction?


The use-case you're describing simply isn't popular enough for jOOQ to make this configurable. E.g. the fact that you like the table to be called MyOrders.TABLE seems very arbitrary from a configuration design perspective. Even if this was implemented, it would be quickly very overengineered.
The SQL-to-jOOQ translation (e.g. here) assumes you're using out-of-the-box code generation configuration. The many reasons why you should use code generation in general are listed here. You haven't stated why you prefer your format. I'm assuming there's a good reason. If not (just preference of style), then I strongly recommend going with the out-of-the-box experience.
In any case, you could probably write a script that will regex-replace well known identifiers from jOOQ's output to your desired format.
